# Excel Shortout key to format axis bound?

Tags: excel, uipath

I’m required to adjust chart axis to show 97 to 100 range as shown in image using send hotkey.
I’ve done(from chart) ctrl 1, ctrl up x3, ctrl 5 to get this far. I need the shortcut key to get to min/max.
(Do refer to screenshot)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6sMo.jpg)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: why do you assume such thing is possible? In my experience it is not possible and the closest thing would be to record a macro and assign a shortcut to it :)

Answer (score 1):

@Yuca is right - there is no built-in hotkey. Instead, you will want to record a macro using [this link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/automate-tasks-with-the-macro-recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b) to get you started.

When you record a macro, it translates the clicks and actions you perform into VBA code. The biggest challenge you will have here is getting VBA code that will be general enough to apply to any chart, but specific enough to format it properly. It can be done, but you may need to record 2 or 3 versions of the macro to get it right.

Another option is to simply use your chart as a template. Read up [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-custom-chart-as-a-template-259a5f9d-a9ec-4b3f-94b6-9f5e55187f2a) for how to save your chart as a template. After it has been saved, you'll be able to add all of your next data sets to a pre-formatted template!